# Customizing OSGi bundles

Tags: osgi

What are the best practices to customize a OSGi bundle shipped to a customer ?
The bundle has a service with 50 APIs, the customer would like to extend or inherit a single API. Does the customer have to create a new bundle or can he modify the existing bundle ?
I would like that the customer does not have to modify the base bundles, is their a way to simply replace the base bundle with a customized bundle ? Also how will process be automated, each time I ship a base bundle, the customer will have extract the bundle contents, repackage this base contents with customized version of classes, with appropriate spring configuration and the rebundle it with a different name or version number. Then replace the base bundle with this custom version in the OSGi container. I am assuming the base bundle only Exports interfaces and not implementation classes, so nobody can inherit implementation classes directly.

Answer (score 1):

Your bundle has a public contract in the packages it exports. Your customer can write a bundle which imports your package and uses them. The customer could also export a package (of his own) which can include types which extends (or delegate) to your types. This exported package is then the public contract of the customer for use by his customers (including company internal customers).

I don't think you want to be in the place where your customer modifies your bundle to customize it.

Comment: Also worth adding: When adding a new bundle, avoid exporting the same packages as the original bundle. This ambiguity about which bundle is the origin of a package is called a "split-package", and it causes all sorts of badness.

Comment: If the new bundle needs access to the original bundle, it can be declared to be a fragment of the original bundle. It will then share a classloader with the original one.